# Function Max mint per wallet is not working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, openzeppelin-contracts

learning solidity and curious how i can limit the minting of my NFT to only 2 per wallet address. Trying to prevent people from minting more then 2 tokens during free mint phase using "mapping" but is not working.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.9 <0.9.0;

import 'erc721a/contracts/extensions/ERC721AQueryable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol';

contract DD is ERC721AQueryable, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

  using Strings for uint256;

  string public baseURI = '';
  string public uriSuffix = '.json';
  
  uint256 public cost;
  uint256 public maxSupply;
  uint256 public maxFreeMint = 4;
  uint256 public maxMintAmountPerWallet = 2;

  mapping(address => uint256) private _freeWalletMints;

  bool public paused = true;

  constructor(
    string memory _tokenName,
    string memory _tokenSymbol,
    uint256 _cost,
    uint256 _maxSupply
  ) ERC721A(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol) {
    setCost(_cost);
    maxSupply = _maxSupply;
  }

  modifier mintCompliance(uint256 _mintAmount) {

    require(_mintAmount > 0, 'Invalid mint amount!');
    require(totalSupply() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, 'Max supply exceeded!');

    _;
  }


  function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliance(_mintAmount){
    if(msg.sender != owner()){
      require(!paused, 'The contract is paused!');
      require(_freeWalletMints[_msgSender()] + _mintAmount <= 2, 'You have already minted');
      if (totalSupply()+_mintAmount > maxFreeMint){
          require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "Insufficient funds!");
        }
      }
      _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount);
    }

  function _startTokenId() internal view virtual override returns (uint256) {
    return 1;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(_tokenId), 'ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token');

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, _tokenId.toString(), uriSuffix))
        : '';
  }

  function setCost(uint256 _cost) public onlyOwner {
    cost = _cost;
  }
  function setBaseURI(string memory _url) public onlyOwner {
    baseURI = _url;
  }

  function setUriSuffix(string memory _uriSuffix) public onlyOwner {
    uriSuffix = _uriSuffix;
  }

  function setPaused(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner nonReentrant {
    (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}('');
    require(os);
  }

  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not increasing the stored value inside the map.

```
  function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliance(_mintAmount){
    if(msg.sender != owner()){
      require(!paused, 'The contract is paused!');
      require(_freeWalletMints[_msgSender()] + _mintAmount <= 2, 'You have already minted');
      // increase the value to prevent new mints in the future
      _freeWalletMints[_msgSender()] += _mintAmount;
      if (totalSupply()+_mintAmount > maxFreeMint){
          require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "Insufficient funds!");
        }
      }
      _safeMint(_msgSender(), _mintAmount);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks but this solution is just for the upcoming Nfts mint not to limit the free mint supply to be minted more than 2 tokens per wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I see what you did here. You made it so that a user cannot with 1 single transaction, mint 2 tokens with your "mintCompliance modifier".

BUT

What you really want is that a single wallet address may never mint more than 2 tokens, irrespectively of the number of transactions.

**What you will need to do is:**
Add a mapping to a user's wallet which tracks the amount of tokens minted. Then on mint function, check the map first to see if the address already minted 2. If so, they may not mint anymore. If not, then they can mint and the mapping is "incremented".

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to limit the mint per transaction, can you provide me code how i can make the contract track the wallet and check it before mint.